# Text Data from X Client for usage in android app

Tags: xorg, x11, android

Is it possible to write a program such that it can capture the data from an X Client to X server and extract only the Text data inside it?

I have to port a legacy application to android and the application only has text data.

There is an X-Server developed in android but it does not have a window manager and [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-xserver/source/browse/XServer/src/au/com/darkside/XServer/Font.java) Here he declared fonts for displaying text data .

libX11 documentation 
XDrawString & XDrawText . How does these draw the text ? ASCII ?

Answer (score 0):

While you can intercept X data through the use of a simple proxy and redirecting the X Client to the server, the chances of intercepting text data is rather small. For a long time applications,i.e., toolkits, have been using their own rendering and only send pixmaps to the X server to display.

Comment: I got this idea because an X-Server is developed in android but it does not have a window manager and [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-xserver/source/browse/XServer/src/au/com/darkside/XServer/Font.java) Here he declared fonts for displaying text data . So , if you can just skim through that code and tell your opinion . That would be great .

Comment: Yes, the X server can do that and if your program actually uses [XDrawText()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/drawing-text/XDrawText.html) you can catch it on the wire. The question is not whether the X Server can draw text, the question is whether your application does draw text using X or other means of rendering. Window managers also have nothing to do with this.

Comment: [IMG](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8796/j5k7.png) .I hope you understand it .

Comment: The image says you do not understand what I told you. The X Client rendering text does not imply it is using Xlib for this purpose. If (!!!) it is, the text will be transmitted as a sequence of bytes on the wire and you can extract them relatively easy by making X use a tcp connection for client/server interaction and intercepting the data at the network layer. If your application does not use XDrawText(), you need to figure out another way. BTW: your image says you are developing an X server ...

Comment: I am assuming that it cannot be done . So , what other options are there for me apart from implementing a Xserver on android .